# Draggable Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can i change the id of div when drag is stop using JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("myDiv").attr('id', 'newid'); ??

Comment: xulfee - perhaps nick's will work (also, mine should have read: $('#myDiv').attr('id', 'newid'); i'd missed out the # symbol. try it again..

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`stop` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop), like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
   stop: function() {
     this.id = "newID"; //calc whatever the new ID is, assign here
   }
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/kE6bx/1/), in the `stop` callback, `this` refers to the dragged element, so do with it what you want :)